# Material Dialog data property with observable creates compile error when building the application

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here is the scenario. I have a service that returns an observable with a defined type.

```
getRecord(recordNum: number): Observable<dataFinderRecord> {
    let params = new HttpParams()
      .set('recordId', recordNum.toString());
    const apiUrl = `${this.variables.api.datafinder}/getrecord`;
    return this.httpClient.get<dataFinderRecord>(apiUrl, {withCredentials: true, params})
      .pipe(
        timeout(15000),
        catchError((error: any) => {
          const logError = {url: apiUrl, error};
          console.log(`Request error in datafinder.getRecord call: `, logError);
          throw error;
        }))
  }
```

That type is defined as follows:

```
export interface dataFinderRecord {
    accessInformation: Array<string>;
    aliases: Array<string>;
    author: string;
    dateRange: string;
    description: string;
    fileFormat: string;
    frequency: Array<string>;
    licensor: string;
    region: Array<string>;
    resourceAdvisory: string;
    resourceName: string;
    resourceUrl: string;
    security: string;
    storageLocation: Array<string>;
    support: Array<string>;
    taxonomy: Array<string>;
  }
```

Now I am binding this observable to the data value of the mat-dialog property of the material dialog component. In addition, rather than defining a new component I am using the TemplateRef in the same component. So its wired up as follow.

```
export class SearchItemDfComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('linkItem') linkItem: resultItem;
  @ViewChild('recordDialog') recordDialog: TemplateRef<HTMLElement>;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private dataFinderService: DatafinderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  viewRecord(recordNum: number) {
    this.dialog.open(this.recordDialog, {
      data: this.dataFinderService.getRecord(recordNum)
    })
  }
}
```

Now the template code looks like the following:

```
<div class="link-header">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="viewRecord(linkItem.id)">{{linkItem.title}}</a>
</div>
<div class="link-source">
  Source: DataFinder
</div>
<ng-template #recordDialog let-data>
  <div *ngIf="(data | async) as record; else loading">
    <h2 mat-dialog-title>{{record.resourceName}}</h2>
    <mat-dialog-content>
      <mg-search-item-df-record [record]="record" [linkItem]="linkItem"></mg-search-item-df-record>
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Close</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #loading>
  <div>...Loading...</div>
</ng-template>
```

When I run this with ng serve everything works as expected. Async pipe does its work and calls the observable and I am able to access the resourceName property of the return record. But when I go to run:

```
ng build --prod
```

It produces the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/content/search/search-item-df/search-item-df.component.html:9:35 - error TS2339: Property 'resourceName' does not exist on type 'never'.

9     <h2 mat-dialog-title>{{record.resourceName}}</h2>
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/content/search/search-item-df/search-item-df.component.ts:10:16
    10   templateUrl: './search-item-df.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component SearchItemDfComponent.
```

Anyone have an idea on how to address this issue? I have found a work around but it isn't ideal and would prefer this to work as configured.

Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be missing some code from getRecord..?

Comment: I went ahead and added it if it would help but its pretty basic scenario.

Comment: Check. Maybe (not sure) you can try something like data: {record: this.dataFinderService.getRecord(recordNum)} and use data.record in your template. Or use the MAT_DIALOG_DATA injection token..?

Comment: Also.. is data (and its type) actually defined in this.recordDialog?

Comment: You could try using [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator), e.g. `{{record!.resourceName}}` or `(data! | async)`. Not sure if it's supported in the Angular templates, which I think use custom parser, but it's worth a shot. It might translate it from never to any.

Comment: @MikeOne  - yes, when I run this code using ng serve data is available and does display the name of the resource.

Comment: @TotallyNewb - thanks for the suggestion, I tried that but the compiler still throws the error that it is being cast as never instead of any

Comment: I might have gotten it wrong. Try `(data | async)!`. See more in the official docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-null-checks). Note that this might depend on the Angular / TS version you're using. Worst case scenario, you can set `strictNullInputTypes` flag to false (this is mentioned in the linked guide as well).